How to get the "source" command working in PowerShell?
I'm trying to execute the "source" command in PowerShell to activate a VM environment for python using Django but it won't let me. It brings up an error message of "source: The term 'source' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.".
I've tried changing into my root directory & executing the command to see if that will change anything, sadly it doesn't. I also tried changing terminals, still giving me the same output. Do I need extra installations to run "source" as a command? I've been reading around & it seems to be built-in for other devs.

I don't know PS, but from the error description, I would conclude that there is no command named source in Powershell.

To source a command in Powershell, you use the . (dot source command, see here) such as with:
. c:\scripts\do_something.ps1

In bash, you can use either . or source but I've never seen the latter in Powershell.
Note that you may need to specify the full filename of the thing you're trying to source.

If you really want a source command, you could try putting something like:
function source { . $args }

into your profile but that seems like a lot of extra work just so you can do some extra typing later on. Aliases and functions are generally used to reduce effort, not increase it :-)

unfortunately it's still giving same error. I am going to uninstall the version of PS I have now to update it then checking to see if updating my PS & its packages to the newest version will help.

@Project.Legion: When you say the same error, did you mean with the . command or with the function? You should use the . command in preference. If it's failing (presumably stating that . is not a command rather than source), you have a serious issue :-) Please clarify which it is, preferably with cut'n'paste of the input and error message.
